# What standards of ECC point compression exist?

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves

The method that I used before to decode EC point from public key led me in a dead end. So I just want to know what yet I could try.

I've got a public key that I don't know how to decode and I am looking for a list of commonly-used encoding/compression schemes.

Here, a part of the test certificate with EC curve parameters (polinomial representation F2m):
[image: description of the used EC curve]

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-jivsov-ecc-compact-05.html Imo it’s a pain in the a.. though. It doesn’t really save much data as ECC points are pretty small anyway.

Comment: Have you tried [SEC1-v2](http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#page=17), algorithm 2.3.4 specifically for point(de) compression?

Comment: So you've got a public key that you don't know how to decode and are looking for a list of commonly-used encoding/compression schemes?

Comment: @Mike You are right!  That's what I'm trying to do. Sec1-v2  doesn't help me. There are no bytes 03 or 02 in front of string

Comment: I guess you can't post the full public key, but can you tell us which algorithm, which curve, etc?

Comment: Of course it is not problem for DH key exchange. It can be seen that blue row has 54 bytes without any information about compression type

Comment: I  has found a solution that was proposed by [Seroussi](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/98/HPL-98-94R1.html) but afterwards i has encountered the problem with calculating Trace operation of an elliptic curve point. I think there are some algorithms to calculate Tr function effectively for some specific elliptic curves. i would be appreciate for such algorithms